# Android: EditText inside a ScrollView doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I have this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar_actionbar" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/post_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/action_bar_layout">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_1">

                       <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/message"
                            style="@style/ItemNewsFeedEditMessage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:hint="@string/news_feed_post_hint"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/keyline_4"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_4"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/keyline_4"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_1"
                            android:overScrollMode="always"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:gravity="top|left" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/picture_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:visibility="gone">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/picture"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />                                  

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </ScrollView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/action_bar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_1"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/keyline_1"
                    android:visibility="invisible">

                    ...

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>               

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried these solutions: https://gist.github.com/laaptu/4cb395fded9a0700fcdb

Unfortunately the behavior is not correct yet: when I add an image in @+id/picture and if the edittext contains lot of lines, the scroll has a strange behavior.

Without image, if the edittext contains lot of lines, the scroll is correct, because it's the edittext scroll and no the global scrollview.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: can you show a screenshot what you mean by strange behavior?

Comment: A screen is not necessary. It's just when I scroll down or up the scrolling moves strangely. Try it, you will have the problem Suraj

Comment: Do you have a relative layout outside? your linear layout has  `android:layout_above="@+id/action_bar_layout"`

Comment: @anthony whats the real problem you face ? whats your expected output? you mean if you have a big size image scroll is like half and stops?

Comment: Your scrollview probably needs `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: Guys, I updated my post with more details on the layout.

Comment: @SurajRao no effect with android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: you have 1 dp's , un closed linear tags invisble views gone views how can we imagine what you actually want!

Comment: @anthony: Layout is not proper, You have opened 4 Linearlayout, but closed only 3. Is this the exact code are you using?. If yes means, please correct the layout.

Comment: Sorry guys, it's ok now, I modified my post.